# Hide actionbar in fragment throws NullPointerException?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying hide the actionbar in a fragment. To do it I'm trying use `getActivity().getActionBar().hide();`, but does throws an exception NullPointerException. I did try use `getSupportActionBar()` but the Eclipse doesn't display autocomplete it only display `getActionBar();`

How can I do it ?

**Fragment**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {           
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            getActivity().getActionBar().hide();  //nullpointerexception in this line       
        }  
}
```

**Exception:**

```
12-05 12:19:02.415: E/AndroidRuntime(16400): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 12:19:02.415: E/AndroidRuntime(16400): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-05 12:19:02.415: E/AndroidRuntime(16400):    at br.com.mypackage.myapp.frags.BatalhaSemOponenteFrag.onCreate(BatalhaSemOponenteFrag.java:71)
12-05 12:19:02.415: E/AndroidRuntime(16400):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1763)
12-05 12:19:02.415: E/AndroidRuntime(16400):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:913)
12-05 12:19:02.415: E/AndroidRuntime(16400):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
12-05 12:19:02.415: E/AndroidRuntime(16400):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
12-05 12:19:02.415: E/AndroidRuntime(16400):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
12-05 12:19:02.415: E/AndroidRuntime(16400):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
12-05 12:19:02.415: E/AndroidRuntime(16400):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-05 12:19:02.415: E/AndroidRuntime(16400):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-05 12:19:02.415: E/AndroidRuntime(16400):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
12-05 12:19:02.415: E/AndroidRuntime(16400):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
12-05 12:19:02.415: E/AndroidRuntime(16400):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 12:19:02.415: E/AndroidRuntime(16400):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-05 12:19:02.415: E/AndroidRuntime(16400):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
12-05 12:19:02.415: E/AndroidRuntime(16400):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
12-05 12:19:02.415: E/AndroidRuntime(16400):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: are you using appcompat ?

Comment: try to hide it in the `onActivityCreated`

Comment: @Blackbelt yep, I'm using appcompat_v7

Comment: then your activity has to extend ActionBarActivity, and you have to cast the return value of getActivity to ActionBarActivity to get getSupportActionBar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using the v4 Support Fragment, i am assuming you would be using appcompat for your activity.
You have to Cast the activity that you get from getActivity() to your actual activity so that it recognises the activity as an appcompat.

Try this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {           
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
((YourActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your minimum SDK? You could change it to 11, just for testing purposes.

Do you call `setContentView` in your activities `onCreate`?

If you're using appcompat you need to call `getSupportActionbar()`.

You could also add `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);` before calling setContentView

Have you defined `Theme.NoTitle` or `windowActionBar` as false in your styles.xml?

Check if the ActionBar is null in the activity.